# ¿Como transformar un output sql en una SFrame?

Tags: python

Tengo un output de una consulta SQL de esta forma :

```
[{'count': 8L, 'subscriber_id': 54, 'eclipse_id': 11294}, {'count': 1L, 'subscriber_id': 54, 'eclipse_id': 11243}, {'count': 1L, 'subscriber_id': 54, 'eclipse_id': 11295}, {'count': 1L, 'subscriber_id': 150, 'eclipse_id': 11313}, {'count': 1L, 'subscriber_id': 150, 'eclipse_id': 11305}, {'count': 7L, 'subscriber_id': 150, 'eclipse_id': 11309}, {'count': 1L, 'subscriber_id': 150, 'eclipse_id': 11267}]
```

en esta forma :

```
({'subscriber_id':["54","54","54","150","150","150"],
'eclipse_id':["11295","11305",,""11309,"11313","11309","11267"],
'count':[8,1,1,1,7,1]})
```

Para utilisarlo econ graphlab en una SFrame :

```
data = graphlab.SFrame({'subscriber_id':["54","54","54","150","150","150"],
    'eclipse_id':["11295","11305",,""11309,"11313","11309","11267"],
    'count':[8,1,1,1,7,1]})
```

¿Pueden ayudarme realizar esta transformación?

En realidad el output de la consulta SQL esta bastante mas largo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres crear un SFrame con las columnas `count | eclipse_id | subscriber_id`
puedes pasarle al constructor de SFrame  la lista de diccionarios directamente y luego usar el método `unpack`:

```
import graphlab as gl

datos = [{'count': 8L, 'subscriber_id': 54, 'eclipse_id': 11294}, {'count': 1L, 'subscriber_id': 54, 'eclipse_id': 11243}, {'count': 1L, 'subscriber_id': 54, 'eclipse_id': 11295}, {'count': 1L, 'subscriber_id': 150, 'eclipse_id': 11313}, {'count': 1L, 'subscriber_id': 150, 'eclipse_id': 11305}, {'count': 7L, 'subscriber_id': 150, 'eclipse_id': 11309}, {'count': 1L, 'subscriber_id': 150, 'eclipse_id': 11267}]
data = gl.SFrame(datos).unpack('X1', column_name_prefix="")
```

**Salida:**

```
>>> data
```

> ```
> Columns:
>   count   int
>   eclipse_id  int
>   subscriber_id   int
>
> Rows: 7
>
> Data:
> +-------+------------+---------------+
> | count | eclipse_id | subscriber_id |
> +-------+------------+---------------+
> |   8   |   11294    |       54      |
> |   1   |   11243    |       54      |
> |   1   |   11295    |       54      |
> |   1   |   11313    |      150      |
> |   1   |   11305    |      150      |
> |   7   |   11309    |      150      |
> |   1   |   11267    |      150      |
> +-------+------------+---------------+
> [7 rows x 3 columns]
> ```